# Trying to install the Teamprise plugin for eclipse is giving "No Software Found" error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, teamprise

I am trying to install the Teamprise plugin for Eclipse, using the url provided by them: http://update.teamprise.com/plugin/3/, and going to Help-> Isntall New Software... It is giving me the error "No Software found" or could not connect, What could be the problem? Could they have changed the url?
Update: It is also giving me : Unable to connect to https://update.teamprise.com/plugin/3/content.xml, Time out, although my internet connection is working fine,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teamprise is acquired by Microsoft and is now being called as Microsoft Visual Studio Team Explorer Everywhere 2010([Teamprise](http://www.teamprise.com/))

You can download the plugin from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4240